# Url configuration for outlook addin using yo generator

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, yo

I have created outlook addin using yo by using the following link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart]. In that link, it was mentioned that provide support url as https://localhost:3000 in the manifest.xml.

I am able to run the application with that URL. But when I change my supportURL to https://[my ip address]:3000
It is still loading the application with localhost and not with my IP address.
Kindly help where else to configure the URL.

Answer (score 1):

SourceLocation element in manifest is correct element to provide URL address of your add-in landing page. Please check its value, it must be set to localhost still. SupportUrl is for providing support URL for your addin.

Documentation Links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/sourcelocation
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/supporturl